# Read from Excel and post message to Teams channel

Tags: automation, microsoft-teams, power-automate

We have an Excel spreadsheet for an on-call rotator schedule. I would like to post a Teams message each Monday with the people assigned for that week.

**Example spreadsheet:**

| Date | Team 1 | Team 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7/4 | X | A |
| 7/11 | Y | C |
| 7/18 | X | B |
| 7/25 | Z | A |

**Example Teams message:**

> On call for week of 7/4: X and A

---

The struggle I am having is reading the data from Excel. I can format the spreadsheet to something that works but I don't know how to extract the team member's based on the day. Is that possible to do with Power Automate?

Comment: please have look into this-https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/excel-bpf-todo-and-more/
hope it's helpful.

Comment: @puter - Please let us know if you need any further assistance here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Filter Query with an expression and the utcNow function in the list rows action.

Below is an example of that approach.

1. Add a Recurrence action
   a. Configure it to run every Monday
2. Add a List Rows action
   a. Use the following value with an expression with a [utcNow](https://aka.ms/logicappexpressions#utcNow) function for the Filter Query

   Date eq '@{utcNow('MM/dd/yyyy')}'
3. Add a Post message in a chat or channel
   a. Use the following expression with a [concat](https://aka.ms/logicappexpressions#concat) function for the Message field

   Concat('On call for week of ', utcNow('M/d'), ': ', first(outputs('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['body/value'])?['Team 1'], ' and ', first(outputs('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['body/value'])?['Team 2'])

[Flow Setup - Get Rota details from Excel and post to Microsoft Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCPEX.png)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. One other follow up question I have - is there a way to tag people when extracting the team members from an Excel sheet? I can create a separate question if needed.

Comment: Yes, I think that would possible. A separate question would be a good idea :)

Comment: Ok, added the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73060438/tag-team-members-in-an-automated-teams-message)